# Variable storage location

Tags: c++, storage-class-specifier

When we declare a variable as

```
char arr[] = "Hello";
```

then the string "Hello" above is located in stack.

But when we declare a variable as

```
char* arr = "Hello";
```

then the string "Hello" is declared in stack or code segment?
If code segment then why code segment and not in stack?

Comment: There are four storage duration models in C++. None of them mentions stack nor code segment. Your second statement is not portable C++.

Comment: "`char* arr = "Hello";`" should be `const char* arr = "Hello";`

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

No. The string literal is not declared in any segment.

It's got *static storage duration* and it's read-only.

Because it's read-only, assigning its address to a `char*` is incorrect. Change it to `char const* arr = "...";`